# Jquery Hide Each Specific Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to hide hide the options according to first change but the code that i've tried doesn't work and doesn't give any errors it seems?

for instance if user selects A, so that D has to be hidden.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M8MfA/

```
<select id="mo" name="mo">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option class="m t t2" value="A">A</option>
     <option class="m t" value="B">B</option>
     <option class="m t" value="C">C</option>
     <option class="m t t2" value="D">D</option>    
     <option class="f t t2" value="E">E</option>                      
     <option class="f t" value="F">F</option>    
</select>      

$("#mo").on("change", function(){
    var exclude = $("option:selected", $(this)).attr("class");
    $(exclude).each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != $("#mo option:selected").val())
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: what are you doing here, $("option:selected", $(this)).attr("class");?

Comment: @jp310: [`jQuery` does take a second context parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exclude` is a class attribute string, which cannot easily be used as a selector. I guess you rather want

```
$("#mo").on("change", function(){
    var selected = $("option:selected", this),
        selectedClass = selected.attr("class");
    $("option", this).not(selected).filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr("class") == selectedClass;
    }).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While using the Jquery Selector, you are missing the "." part.

ex $('.' + exclude).....

Also since exclude will contain multiple classes, you may want to split them into an array and a dot to each. Or may be there is a better method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
   <select id="mo" name="mo">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option class="m t t2" value="A">A</option>
     <option class="m t" value="B">B</option>
     <option class="m t" value="C">C</option>
     <option class="m t t2" value="D">D</option>    
     <option class="f t t2" value="E">E</option>                      
     <option class="f t" value="F">F</option>    
   </select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $(document).on('change','#mo',function(){
 var exclude = $("option:selected", $(this)).attr("class");
    $('#mo option').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("class") != exclude)
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Demoi:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZnfX7/2/